# Unavailable Prometheus service with WAL segment loaded entries in log file

Tags: prometheus

I've just setup for the first time, Prometheus on Docker using this docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

volumes:
    prometheus_data: {}

services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/:/etc/prometheus/
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles'
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    links:
      - alertmanager:alertmanager
    restart: always
```

The problem is that after a few minutes CPU gets overloaded and RAM (8GB VPS) gets consumed up to almost full capacity. Service becomes unavailable.
Looking at container's logs, hundreds of entries like the following show up continously:

```
level=info ts=2021-10-02T08:01:09.966Z caller=head.go:577 component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=270 maxSegment=355
```

Tried to restart container, but nothing changes. Tried also to update Prometheus image to the latest version (from 2.29.0 to 2.30.2).
I'm currently looking up in the Internet, but haven't found a solution yet...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The following article contains some technical details on WAL usage in TSDBs - https://valyala.medium.com/wal-usage-looks-broken-in-modern-time-series-databases-b62a627ab704

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loading the WAL is an integral part of starting Prometheus. Otherwise, you would lose data that had not yet been persisted on shutdown. Unfortunately, this is known to be resource-intensive and takes a while. Your only "solution" is to delete the WAL (`rm -r data/wal`), but that would entail losing some of your data. Otherwise, just wait.

In the future, you can enable the [experimental in-memory snapshot feature](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/feature_flags/#memory-snapshot-on-shutdown) (new to v2.30), which reduces startup time.

Comment: Hi Levi,
The only way I found to solve this, was to install it on a more powerful VM (4CPUs + 16GB RAM) with dedicated CPUs instead of shared ones...
Now replaying WAL segments is a matter of seconds!

Comment: By this advice, we lost all data not just some :(